# Dose Spark ALS solve binary classification?

Tags: apache-spark-ml, recommendation-engine

I am trying to build a recommender system. The data has three columns: userID, itemID, behavior (buy or pv).
I am wondering can I use ALS?
A parameter in ALS is the rating column. I actually do not have ratings, so should I imagine the behavior is a two-class rating and pass behavior into it? But how should I evaluate the model? I guess I can only use regression evaluator but not classification evaluator like AUC
I am understanding ALS only solves the regression problem. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of implicit preference. The `trainImplicit` classmethod can be used.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.recommendation.ALS